# How to create multi-dimensional jagged arrays in VbScript?

Tags: vbscript, jagged-arrays, dynamic-arrays

I need to create multi-dimensional array of strings. Each row of the array can have varying number of strings. Something like the follwing code:

```
twoDimension = Array(Array())  
ReDim Preserve twoDimension(3)  
For i = 0 to 2  
 If i = 1 Then  
  twoDimension(i) = Array(1,2,3)  
 End If  
 If i = 2Then  
     twoDimension(i) = Array(1,2,3,4,5)  
   End If  
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a dictionary

```
Set a = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
a.Add 0, Array(1,2,3)
a.Add 1, Array(4,5,6)
MsgBox a.Count
MsgBox a.Item(0)(2)
MsgBox a.Item(1)(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having jagged arrays in VBScript. There are some minor issues with your code (`ReDim` to 3 but only assigning values to 2, unnecessarily using a `For` loop to assign values), but in general, that's the correct syntax to use.

```
Option Explicit

Dim twoDimension, i, j

twoDimension = Array(Array())  
ReDim Preserve twoDimension(2)

twoDimension(1) = Array(1,2,3)
twoDimension(2) = Array(1,2,3,4,5)

For i = 0 To UBound(twoDimension)
  For j = 0 To UBound(twoDimension(i))
    WScript.Echo "(" & i & "," & j & ") = " & twoDimension(i)(j)
  Next
Next
```